# 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_columns' with inherits

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

i really wnat that when its phone only have one employee asigment
when its gps only one vehicle, and when its gprs only one costumer
without dulicated a one2one relation and it came this error
'NoneType' object has no attribute '_columns'

```
 class dispositivos(osv.osv):
    _name = 'dispositivos'
    _description = 'Inventario Dispositivos'
    _inherits = {'chips': "chips_id",
                 'fleet.vehicle': 'fleet.vehicle_id',
                 'base.res_partner': 'base.partner_id',
                 'hr.employee': 'hr.employee_id' }

    _columns = {         
                'name' : fields.selection ([('phone','Telefono'),
                                            ('gps','GPS'),                 
                                            ('gprs','GPRS')],
                                        'Tipo de dispositivo',
                                        track_visibility='onchange',
                                        order = True), 
                'imei':fields.char('Imei',required = True),              
                'num_serie' : fields.char('Numero  dispositivo'),              
                'marca' : fields.char('Marca del dispositivo'),
                'modelo' : fields.char('Modelo del dispositivo'),
                'ide_gps' : fields.char('IDE del dispositivo'),
                'num_serie_bateria' : fields.char('Bateria del telefono'),
                'chips_id' : fields.many2one('chips','Chip del dispositivo'),
                'vehicle_id' : fields.many2one('fleet.vehicle', 'Vehiculo'),
                'partner_id' :fields.many2one'res.partner', 'Cliente',domain="[('costumer','=',True)]"),
                'employee_id' : fields.many2one('hr.employee', 'Empleado'),
                'activo' : fields.boolean('Dispositivo en uso'),

           }

     _defaults = {
             'activo' : False,
             }

dispositivos()

class chips(osv.osv):
    _name = 'chips'
    _description = 'Inventario Chips'

    _columns = {                         
            'name' : fields.char('Imei del Chip', required=      True),               
            'numero_tel' : fields.char('Numero de telefono'),
            'marca' : fields.char('Compañia'),
            'activo' : fields.boolean('Dispositivo en uso'),               
           }

    _defaults = {
             'activo' : False,
             }

chips()
```

Comment: If you pasted your code exactly as it is in your source file, try removing the space character in the first line and the _defaults dictionary is not indented properly... python is pretty sensitive to whitespace.

Comment: i edited but i use eclipse and it marks me when is not properly writed

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
class dispositivos(osv.osv):
    _name = 'dispositivos'
    _description = 'Inventario Dispositivos'
    _inherits = {'chips': "chips_id",
             'fleet.vehicle': 'vehicle_id',
             'base.res_partner': 'res_partner_id',
             'hr.employee': 'employee_id' }
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to simple i moved the class chips before class dispositivos and Works thanks for all